# LibGDX: What's the fastest way to render scalable-vector-based shapes?

Tags: java, performance, opengl, libgdx, rendering

In my game (created using LibGDX) I have a gameworld filled with a lot of **circles changing their size continiously**. Because there are so **many** circles I want to maximize their **rendering-performance**: I've heard of the ShapeRenderer, but it seems like that it is not the best in case of performance. The PixMap is also no solution because my circles should be **vector-based**. 
Is their another faster solution too? And is the ShapeRenderer really that slow?

PS: I'm already using chunks to reduce the render time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ShapeRenderer (circle in particular), if we look at the method, radius does not effect performance, segments is where the work is. And this is most likely what is hurting you, as you scale up in size, you increase the segments for detail.

I am not sure about there being opengl native vector graphics either... I think ultimately to reach the graphics card, you need to eventually become vertices and polygons (if you are filling). So actually, I think the Pixmap solution is the one you might be looking for. You compute the segments and the polygons to draw once (at the highest resolution you need).

With the Pixmap you should be able to do this in a way which is as performant as any other rendering of a Texture which you change sizes using the scaling variables (which should be as performant as not changing the scale). As you can see from the circle draw method that the ShapeRenderer uses, the circle is still really just describing a polygon (you are just computing its geometry every time).

If you want to give the Pixmap option a go, here is some code to get you bootstrapped.

Here is a kotlin function for building a PolygonSprite. You will have to do the maths for plotting the vertices of your circle, but you can probably use the circle draw method to get an idea for that. If you compute your geometry for a radius of 1, then you can just use your x/y scale to set the radius at whatever size you want.

```
    fun polygonSprite(points: Array<Vector2>): PolygonSprite {
        val pix = Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
        pix.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF.toInt())
        pix.fill()
        val textureSolid = Texture(pix)
        val vertices = FloatArray(points.size * 2)
        val triangleIndices = triangulator.computeTriangles(vertices)
        for (i in 0..points.size - 1) {
            val point = points.get(i)
            val offset = i * 2
            vertices[offset] = point.x
            vertices[offset + 1] = point.y
        }
        val polyReg = PolygonRegion(TextureRegion(textureSolid),
                vertices, triangleIndices.toArray())
        val poly = PolygonSprite(polyReg)
        return poly
    }
```

And here is some rendering code. It takes into account relative positioning of the shape from the parent Body and some other stuff:

```
fun render(camera: OrthographicCamera) {
    val parentRotation = (me().physicsRoot.rotationR() * MathUtils.radDeg) 
    val parentTransform = me().physicsRoot.transform
    val myPosition = vec2(offsetX, offsetY)
    parentTransform.mul(myPosition)
    poly.color = color.get()
    poly.setOrigin(0f, 0f)
    poly.setPosition(myPosition.x, myPosition.y)
    poly.rotation = parentRotation + rotationD
    poly.setScale(scaleX, scaleY)
    poly.draw(JJ.B.renderWorld.polyBatch)
    recycle(myPosition)
}
```

Also, don't make a new one of these for every one, try and reuse them.

PS: Another option is to make a circle shader :D